# is it possible to use IPFS Hash to ensure file integrity?

Tags: ipfs, hash

My question is if i can use the IPFS Reference/Hash to ensure file integrity. In other words if i have a file can i use a specific Hashfunction to ensure that the generated Hash of that file is equal to the IPFS Hash of that file and therefore the file didnt change. Or do i need to generate an extra Hash for this purpose (f.e. sha256)?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From IPFS docs:

```
-n,          --only-hash           bool   - Only chunk and hash - do not write to disk.
```

So what you might want to do is:

```
ipfs add --only-hash <ipfs-path>
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/).